# Pylint is showing error all return statements in a function should return an expression

Tags: python, pylint

I have 3 function. invalid_response,valid_response,lambda_handler

- I got proper out in AWS account. But running through pylint  i got error Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. (inconsistent-return-statements)
- I tried to put every thing in Lambda_handler still got error

Below is the code

```
def invalid_response():
    response = {
        'statusCode': 404,
        'body': json.dumps("NA")
    }
    return response

def valid_response(response):
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)
    }
    return response
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
        event_value = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']
        if event_value == '' or event_value is None:
            aresponse = invalid_response()
            return aresponse
        if event_value is not None or \
                event_value['q'][0] is not None:
            event_value_new = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['q'][0]
            response = read_s3(event_value_new)
            if response:
                resp = valid_response(response)
            else:
                resp = invalid_response()
            return resp
```

Comment: lambda_handler can fall off the end without returning a value.   You need an unconditional return value at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pylint` is annoyed because there is a chance that you reach the end of the function without returning anything, while you are returning values withing the conditionals. `Pylint` Does not like this, since it can lead to code that is more likely to introduce bugs and crashes due to an inability to process the reutned `None` value.

The cleanest response would be to add some default response to the end of the function so that all execution branches return the same type of value.

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
        event_value = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']
        if event_value == '' or event_value is None:
            aresponse = invalid_response()
            return aresponse
        if event_value is not None or \
                event_value['q'][0] is not None:
            event_value_new = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['q'][0]
            response = read_s3(event_value_new)
            if response:
                resp = valid_response(response)
            else:
                resp = invalid_response()
            return resp

        # it is logically possible to reach this block
        return invalid_response()
```